# powershell email stdout & stderr

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a powershell script email stdout & stderr to myself after each run of a windows scheduled task. What I have now is:

```
& python.exe script.py 2>&1 | tee -Variable allOutput
if($allOutput){
  Send-MailMessage -To "<myself@email.com>" `
      -From "Cron Daemon <root@server.com>" `
      -Subject "job output" `
      -Body $allOutput | Out-String `
      -SmtpServer "smtp-relay.server.com"
}
```

The variable `$allOutput` is of type System.Object[], and I need to convert it to a string. How should I do that?

edit: it looks like the first object in `$allOutput` is a warning from my python script that I'd like to convert to a string:
python.exe : C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:322: Warning: (1264, "Out of range value for column `id` at row 1")
At C:\powershellscript.ps1:1 char:1
+ & python.exe script.py 2) ...

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

CategoryInfo      : NotSpecified: (C:\Users...pth' at row 1")

:String) [], RemoteException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: Can you post an example of whats in $allOutput. but you may be able to just use $allOutput.ItemArray[0]

Comment: look at the `-join` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *immediate* fix is to replace
`-Body $allOutput | Out-String` 
with
`-Body ($allOutput | Out-String)`

In order to pass another command's output as an *argument* to a cmdlet, you must enclose it in `(...)`; in the case of *multiple* commands, use `$(...)`.

However, use of `Out-String` will create "noisy" multi-line representations of the stderr output lines from the Python script, so it's better to use `-join`:

```
-Body ($allOutput -join "`r`n")
```